# Объеденить 3 функции в одну

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.first_upload').click(function(){
    $('.upload_first').slideToggle().css('display', 'block');
  });
  $('.second_upload').click(function(){
      $('.upload_second').slideToggle().css('display', 'block');
  });
   $('.third_upload').click(function(){
      $('.upload_third').slideToggle().css('display', 'block');
  });
```

Как объеденить эти 3 функции, в одну, но чтобы работали все 3.

Comment: покажи разметку чтоб точнее сказать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно всем тегам с классами `first_upload`/`second_upload`/`third_upload`  дать общий класс, например `upload` (а эти классы уже удалить). Аналогично делаем с `upload_first`/`upload_second`/`upload_third` (хотя с ними это делать даже не обязательно).

Далее применяем клик по элементу с классом `upload` и говорим: вот относительно **конкретно тебя** нужно на такой-то элемент применять вот эту функцию.

Пример:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.upload', function(){
  $(this).next('.upload-relative').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.upload {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.upload-relative {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload"></div>
<div class="upload-relative"></div>

<div class="upload"></div>
<div class="upload-relative"></div>

<div class="upload"></div>
<div class="upload-relative"></div>
```

Вместо `.next('.upload-relative')`  может быть что-то другое, в зависимости от вашей разметки, которую я не знаю.